# Get Obj-C Cocoapod API to be consumed in Swift 3.0 apps

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods, swift3, api-design

My situation is the following:

I have a SDK written in Obj-C and distributed as a Cocoapod. It is currently consumed by my and my users apps. My app is written mainly in Swift, and I consume the pod using a bridging header since my SDK and several other 3rd-party `pod`'s I am consuming are not exported as frameworks so usage of `use_frameworks!` in `podfile` won't work.

I've migrated my app to Swift 3.0 using the XCode 8 migration tool but now it won't compile against the Cocoapod SDK.

for example - post migration call to my SDK:

```
SparkCloud.sharedInstance().getDevices({ (devices:[Any]?, error:Error?) -> Void in ...
```

Will cause the following compile time error:

`Cannot convert value of type '([AnyObject]?, NSError?) -> Void' to expected argument type '(([Any]?, Error?) -> Void)?'`

which makes sense since NSError is now Error and untyped nullable NSArray from Obj-c now resolves to [Any], but my SDK does not reflect that.

Obj-C SDK relevant line is:

```
-(NSURLSessionDataTask *)getDevices:(nullable void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable sparkDevices, NSError * _Nullable error))completion;
```

I tried to add `NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT` on my Obj-C function headers and write a wrapper Swift file for exposing the "right" interface to Swift 3.0 but I am puzzled on how do I package and consume this new Swift "header" file in my apps given that the SDK is a Cocoapod Library (not framework), as well as how to modify the `podspec` file for that.

Any help / tips / directions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check the build settings for the pod in question and see if 'use legacy swift' is set to false/off

Comment: there's some change in `Any` and `AnyObject` in swift3

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Swift 2.3 in xcode 8 then you can use legacy.

Comment: 3.0 is a replacement for 2.3. He will have to update it eventually.